# Transform map to mapPartition using pyspark

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyspark

I am trying to load a tensorflow model from disk and predicting the values.

Code

```
def get_value(row):
    print("**********************************************")
    graph = tf.Graph()
    rowkey = row[0]
    checkpoint_file = "/home/sahil/Desktop/Relation_Extraction/data/1485336002/checkpoints/model-300"
    print("Loading model................................")
    with graph.as_default():
        session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
            allow_soft_placement=allow_soft_placement,
            log_device_placement=log_device_placement)
        sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)
        with sess.as_default():
            # Load the saved meta graph and restore variables
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("{}.meta".format(checkpoint_file))
            saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)
            input_x = graph.get_operation_by_name("X_train").outputs[0]
            dropout_keep_prob = graph.get_operation_by_name("dropout_keep_prob").outputs[0]
            predictions = graph.get_operation_by_name("output/predictions").outputs[0]
            batch_predictions = sess.run(predictions, {input_x: [row[1]], dropout_keep_prob: 1.0})
            print(batch_predictions)
            return (rowkey, batch_predictions)
```

I have a RDD which consists of a tuple (rowkey, input_vector). I want to use the loaded model to predict the score/class of the input.

Code to call get_value()

```
result = data_rdd.map(lambda iter: get_value(iter))
result.foreach(print)
```

The problem is every time I call the map, the model is loaded everytime for each tuple and it takes a lot of time.

I am thinking of loading the model using **mapPartitions** and then use map to call **get_value** function.
I have no clue as how to convert the code to a mapPartition where I load the tensorflow model only once per parition and reduce the running time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the below code is a huge improvement as it uses mapPartitions.

Code

```
def predict(rows):
    graph = tf.Graph()
    checkpoint_file = "/home/sahil/Desktop/Relation_Extraction/data/1485336002/checkpoints/model-300"
    print("Loading model................................")
    with graph.as_default():
        session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
            allow_soft_placement=allow_soft_placement,
            log_device_placement=log_device_placement)
        sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)
        with sess.as_default():
            # Load the saved meta graph and restore variables
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("{}.meta".format(checkpoint_file))
            saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)
        print("**********************************************")
        # Get the placeholders from the graph by name
        input_x = graph.get_operation_by_name("X_train").outputs[0]
        dropout_keep_prob = graph.get_operation_by_name("dropout_keep_prob").outputs[0]
        # Tensors we want to evaluate
        predictions = graph.get_operation_by_name("output/predictions").outputs[0]

        # Generate batches for one epoch
        for row in rows:
            X_test = [row[1]]
            batch_predictions = sess.run(predictions, {input_x: X_test, dropout_keep_prob: 
            yield (row[0], batch_predictions)


result = data_rdd.mapPartitions(lambda iter: predict(iter))
result.foreach(print)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I get your question correctly, but we can optimise your code a bit here.

```
graph = tf.Graph()

checkpoint_file = "/home/sahil/Desktop/Relation_Extraction/data/1485336002/checkpoints/model-300"

with graph.as_default():
        session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
            allow_soft_placement=allow_soft_placement,
            log_device_placement=log_device_placement)
        sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)

s = sess.as_default()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("{}.meta".format(checkpoint_file))
saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)


input_x = graph.get_operation_by_name("X_train").outputs[0]
dropout_keep_prob = graph.get_operation_by_name("dropout_keep_prob").outputs[0]
predictions = graph.get_operation_by_name("output/predictions").outputs[0]

session_pickle = cPickle.dumps(sess)

def get_value(key, vector, session_pickle):
    sess = cPickle.loads(session_pickle)
    rowkey = key
    batch_predictions = sess.run(predictions, {input_x: [vector], dropout_keep_prob: 1.0})
    print(batch_predictions)
    return (rowkey, batch_predictions



result = data_rdd.map(lambda (key, row): get_value(key=key, vector = row ,  session_pickle = session_pickle))
result.foreach(print)
```

So you can serialize your tensorflow session. Though I haven't tested your code here. Run this and leave a comment.

Comment: error pops up
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sahil/Desktop/Relation_Extraction/temp.py", line 465, in <module>
    session_pickle = cPickle.dumps(sess)
TypeError: can't pickle SwigPyObject objects
`